# How to find and focus an existing node?

Tags: node-editor

The title says everything. Sometimes in a very complex nodetree, I want to quickly find where an existing node is by it's name/label. (I don't mean the "Search..." in Shift A menu)

I remember we used to have such feature, but cannot find it. Or something wrong with my memory...

Answer (score 4):

Just got it. It is by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> in node editor. (I know the answer is a very short one, but there really is no need to extend it with nonsense)

And thanks to the dev who ever developed it.